# Isn't C1 and C2 nulling the input signal?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier

I am a relative newbie to electronics.

Looking at the following schematics I see something strange: C1 and C2 at the input.

I always knew that capacitors block DC signals and let AC pass. By having these caps to ground aren't them letting the signal go to ground, or in other words, grounding the signal zero or nulling it?

I do not understand them and now I see also C9 and C10 at the output.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those capacitors are marked `101`, or 100 pF, they have a reactance of ~80k Ohms 
 for a 20 kHz signal.

They're there to shunt higher frequencies (radio and the like) to ground.

The reactance of a capacitor is calculated with the formula \$ Xc =  \dfrac{1}{ 2 \pi f C}\$

Comment: ahhhh...to prevent the amplification of radio wave interference! fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: More likely than amplification of them, is they demodulate and turn into noise and artifacts in your output.

Comment: thats why I was messing with this circuit on a breadboard and when I touched the fingerprint sensor of my iPhone (I was using it as audio input), I heard a noise, like a "sewing machine noise", probably equivalent to the sensor waiting the CPU to read the fingerprint!

Comment: if you don't mind just one question to illustrate... how these capacitors are calculated? I mean, you say that 100pF have a reactance of 80k ohms but why 80 is chosen and not 300, 1000 or 20? I see that C9 and C10 have different values compared to C1 and C2. How did these values were calculated?

Comment: @SpaceDog: The capacitor C1 forms a low-pass filter with P1. The values chosen give a corner frequency of 160 kHz. 100 pF may have been chosen because it is a nice, round number... choosing fewer different values for components reduces the cost.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why C1 and C2 is 100pf and C9 and C10 is 150nF. If the idea is to filter from a certain frequency up why aren't the two capacitors the same value?

Comment: @spacedog c9 and c10 are 150nF, I guess as that's their recommended value from the datasheet. It says there's danger of oscillation if they're smaller than that. They are there to keep the amplifier stable.